# How to find the values ​with a voltmeter and ammeter?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, diodes, proteus

I'd like to know how the values ​​obtained in that image are derived.

And I would like to know how to set the transformer in Proteus. What should I set if I want to use a transformer 220 V 24 V 0 24 V to connect the circuit?

[image]

Comment: Noting, if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 2):

> *I'd like to know how the values ​​obtained in that image are derived.*

I've marked up some key notes on your diagram: -

[image]

- The first point is that although you think you might be specifying an RMS voltage of 220 volts; in fact you are specifying the peak voltage.
- The second point is that you can calculate the turns ratio of the transformer using the square root of the inductance ratio hence \$\sqrt{\frac{220}{5.5}}\$ is 6.325.
- This means that the peak secondary voltage will be 34.79 volts. After the bridge rectifier (it drops about 1.4 volts) the DC peak voltage will be 33.39 volts and, that's pretty much what the voltmeter says
- Capacitor C1 smooths out the ripple and maintains a fairly steady voltage of 33.4 volts (in this circuit)
- Zener diode D1 is rated at 15 volts hence, its associated meter reads 15 volts

I can't tell you why the ammeter reads 0 amps.

> *What should I set if I want to use a transformer 220v 24v 0 24v to
> connect the circuit?*

That's equivalent to having a secondary voltage of 48 volts when 220 volts is present at the input. That's a step-down turns ratio of 4.583 or, an inductance ratio of \$4.583^2\$ = 21. So, if you kept 220 henries as the primary inductance, your secondary inductance would be about 10.5 henries.

Comment: Current in R2 is "out" of view. 15 V / 10 kOhm = 1.5 mA (not visible until it would reach 10 mA)

Comment: I like your answers when they are straightforward and elegant like this.